# How do I import an image in intellij (JAVA)

Tags: java, image, intellij-idea, jframe, imageicon

I'm fairly new to coding and was trying to make a simple GUI with JAVA Swing. I wanted to place an image in a label but for some reason does the image does not show when I run the Code. Are there some requirements I don't know of or did I do something wrong?

```
package Part2Lables;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //Label = a GUI display area for a string of text, an image, or both
        ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("Kakashi.png");


        JLabel label = new JLabel(); // create a label
        label.setText("This is text in a label"); // set text to the label
        label.setIcon(image);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(500,500);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.add(label);

    }
}
```

[This is the code I used (I did use imports but they are not visible in the pic.)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GYl36.png)

Comment: Where did you place the “Kakashi.png” file in your file system?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html

Comment: You can see it in the linked picture I dont know the exact name of it

Comment: As explained in Basil's link, you may want to try to use an URL instead of a String. Something like new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("Kakashi.png")). I don't know if the String constructor picks media from the resource folder. At least, it should work with the URL constructor.